# sphere texture mapping error

Tags: directx, textures, shader, texture-mapping

i use `D3DXCreateSphere` method to create sphere mesh. and i want to apply an earth texture on it. i calculate the texture coordinate in pixel shader with following code:

```
sampler ShadeSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture   = (ShadeTex);
    AddressU = Mirror;
    AddressV = Mirror;
    MinFilter = LINEAR;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
};
PS_OUTPUT PSMain(VS_OUTPUT input){

PS_OUTPUT output = (PS_OUTPUT)0;

vector uv;

uv.x = 0.5 + atan2(input.normal.z, input.normal.x) / piMul2;
uv.y = 0.5f - asin(input.normal.y) / pi;

vector b = tex2D(ShadeSampler, uv.xy);

output.diffuse = b * input.diffuse;

return output;
}
```

i use `D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx` method to create the `IDirect3DTexture9`, but when i enable the mipmap capability by using `D3DX_DEFAULT` value for the `MipLevels` parameter, the render result goes a little wrong that there is always one pixel line at the seam. the picture below shows the problem, but when i disable the mipmap capability by using `D3DX_FROM_FILE` value for the `MipLevels` parameter, the line disappears. i don't know why this would happen, any advice?

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702285/why-the-sphere-texture-map-can-not-actually-match)?  Both have a screenshot of the earth with a line artifact.

Comment: @DavidM both the questions are posted by me, they are caused by different reasons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem before and it is caused, as you found out by the mipmapping. You're remapping the texture coordinates and at this line there is the seam from u = 1 to 0. This big jump is detected by the mipmapping algorithm and a very low mipmap is chosen, which causes the pixels to have a wrong color. The seam have a thickness of 2 pixels, because mipmapping is determined with the gradient function ddx and ddy of a 2x2 pixelblocks. When the seam is exactly in this block the error occurs.

I solved it by disabling the mipmapping for this geometry, but if you need it you could use the method `tex2Dgrad` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to repair the gradients at this seam or use `tex2Dlod` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) in the shader and determine the miplevel by yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer helps me a lot, i even didn't know ddx,ddy things before, lol! but i understand them now.

Comment: Using tex2Dlod(TextureSampler, float4(u, v, 0, 0)); solved this same problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

To me this seems to be a matter of [texture wrapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Have you tried the various options of the D3DRS_WRAPx render state? For example,

```
IDirect3DDevice9::SetRenderState(D3DRS_WRAP0, D3DWRAP_U);
```